# azure media service aes jwt token

Tags: azure, aes, azure-media-services

I use azure media player with aes content protection.
Login our server get token, but that set token in html or javascript.
If our user copy the token and paste to himself html page.
My content protection will return the key.
Any way to limit one token one user?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can check http://gtrifonov.com/2015/01/24/mvc-owin-azure-media-services-ad-integration/ to get idea how to restrict video playback based on jwt token user group claims. Technically you can create restrictions by checking any claim in a token. For example user email or id. But you need to configure these restrictions for video using sdks.

Some unit tests can be found  here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services/blob/d543e77ec47691110575078e8df71c55c2d7128e/test/net/unit/TokenRestrictionTemplateSerializerTests.cs.

Code below for example will create restriction that only users which token contains claim 'Rental' will be able to get key.

```
TokenRestrictionTemplate template = new TokenRestrictionTemplate(TokenType.JWT);
            template.Audience = _sampleAudience;
            template.Issuer = _sampleIssuer;
    template.RequiredClaims.Add(new TokenClaim("Rental", "true"));
            try
            {
                TokenRestrictionTemplateSerializer.Serialize(template);
            }
```

If you using Azure AD you can find list of supported claims here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/. 
For example you can use claim "unique_name" to check.

In practice you would probably will go with security group claims since it is easy to manage compare to granting permissions to individual user names.

Nothing stop authenticated user to copy token and mitigate this you can do following:

- Switch to DRM protection like PlayReady and Widewine. More protection and restriction options

  - Minimize token lifetime by crafting your own token instead of using user session tokens from Active Directory or other providers. You need to have some mechanism to request token right before user actually plays video. Content key retrieval need to be performed once to decrypt playback, so if two events are close together you are minimizing possibility of reusing same token.
  - You can create proxy which retrieves content key based on custom logic - for example  to serve content key only once. And use you proxy as endpoint for content keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the expiry time to less than 5 minutes - so the token expires in a short period of time, just enough for user to retrieve the key. Therefore, so when user passes the token to another, the token wont be useful anymore (probably expired). As said, what you mentioned is one-time token, which we don't support today.